# How can I validate an Excel cell reference that includes a sheet name?

Tags: c#, regex

I want to validate a cell reference in an Excel sheet formula.

Valid strings:

1. `Sheet1!A1`
2. `'Sheet!!'!A1`

I am using following expression but it is not working.

```
"^='?[^[]/\*]*'?!+[A-Z]+[0-9]+$"
```

Comment: can you post your code ?

Comment: We have two major kinds of regex questions: "please send teh regex codez" and "regex not working". Let's turn this into the third kind. Is it failing to match valid inputs? Is it accepting some invalid inputs? Which ones? "not working" is not a problem description.

Comment: What are the double quotes for? Are they part of the regex? Are they the string delimiters? If they're string delimiters, you should be using verbatim strings instead of regular strings. When writing paths and regexes, one does not even think about it: verbatim strings from the start. You shouldn't be using a JavaScript regex validator to test .NET regexes. Regexes come in all various flavors depending on the platform/language/library. To validate .NET regexes you should use .NET. I recommend you give [LinqPad](http://www.linqpad.net/) a try.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh some other problem.

Its working now

```
^='?[^/\[]*]*'?!{1}[A-Z]+[0-9]+$
```

Comment: No it isn't. `Regex.IsMatch("Sheet1!A1",@"^='?[^/\[]*]*'?!{1}[A-Z]+[0-9]+$")` is false.

Comment: You missed "=" Valid string is "=Sheet1!A1" Don't know how its emitted in original question.

Comment: the above would not correctly catch if a * character was present in the sheet name.  Here's an updated regex to get that working

`^='?[^/\[]\*]*'?!{1}[A-Z]+[0-9]+$`

Answer (score 3):

```
Regex re = new Regex(@"^=('?[^']+'?|[^!]+)![A-Z]+[0-9]+$");
bool isOk = re.IsMatch("=Sheet1!A1");
```

Change the `[^!]` to whatever characters you do not want in the sheet's name.

It will match anything with the format `='<anything>'!XN` or `=<anything>!XN` where X is at least one uppercase letter and N is at least one digit.

**Edit**:
I am not sure if OP wants the `=` character at the start or not (the original post had it). If you don't, remove the `=` character from the start of the regular expression.

Comment: Specially for you I have tried both expressions and it evaluates to `true`.
His post is edited now, he removed the equality character from the start, not sure if it is intended or not...

Comment: Oh, nevermind. It's fine. +1. Somehow I was not copy-pasting correctly :(

Answer (score 0):

this one should work:
=?(\s|\w)+![A-Za-z]+\d+