# Range.Formula returns a string that uses cell reference, why?

Tags: c#, excel, vsto, excel-interop

I am having a problem with `Range.Formula`. The code snippet is below (assume Range object has been created and is not null)

```
string formula;
formula = Range.Formula;//it returns whatever is written in the formula, even the cell reference
```

Let's say I have such a formula, `=MyCalc(41, A1)`, that uses the relative cell reference. And in cell A1, there's a value, 100.

So the value of the string variable `formula`, is always `=MyCalc(41, A1)` instead of `=MyCalc(41, 100)` which is the result I wanted.

I wonder if there's a way to let Range.Formula avoid returning cell reference. Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Doesn't this come down to magical thinking - that you want it to do *some* evaluation of the formula, and substitute the referenced cell values, but not evaluate the complete formula (e.g. invoke `MyCalc` and just give you the result)? Why would you expect it to do this?

Comment: I can't pass a formula with cell reference in it onto the web service because it'd yield wrong result. So I need to do some pre-processing and reconstruct the formula that will have values in it.

Comment: You are requesting a bug - the formula has to be the formula that was entered, any other result would be incorrect. You can attempt to get the result from a formula using Evaluate (may fail if there are uncalculated cells in the upstream dependency chain), or the current Value from a cell, but the formula in a cell is the formula in a cell.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation Charles. But the thing is the web method can't accept the formula like this, `MyCalc(41, A1)`, as A1 is not a correct parameter. So I have to somehow convert cell reference to a value and place it in the formula that will be passed into the web method. That's the trouble I am having.

Comment: But if its an Excel formula (and since you are getting the formula from a Range then it presumably is an Excel Formula) then A1 is indeed a correct parameter. And (assuming the spreadsheet has been calculated) you could get the value in the cell resulting from the formula and pass that to your web service. Or else your web service will have to duplicate the Excel formula parsing and calculation engine.

Answer (score 0):

The whole point of the formula is to give you exactly what was typed in there. You could write a method which goes through a formula and recursively gets the values for that cell range.

The reason why this is not done for you is it could incur a lot of recursion. What if Cell A1 (in your example) actaull references cell B2, which references C100... and so on.

I would write a function that takes a cell reference and gets the VALUE (getCellValue) (not formula). Then I would write a function that gets the Formula, check for cell references using a regex, and call the getCellValue on all the references.

Comment: This is very similar to what I am thinking. I am thinking of using `string.split` and substitute cell reference string with cell value.

Comment: Well, take a look into regular expressions, they would do the job much better: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4932283/how-can-i-validate-an-excel-cell-reference-that-includes-a-sheet-name